# How to have Cucumber render CSS before checking content?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

So, the HTML of the page has `Hi There` and I'm using CSS to convert it to `HI THERE`.

I run cucumber to check if the page has `HI THERE` on it (as it should since that's the end result.

Yet when I run cucumber, I get an error. `HI THERE` is not on the page... I edit the tests to instead look for `Hi there` and it passes.

Key Question: How do I tell Cucumber that I need it to render the CSS before giving me an OK answer?

**Edit**: So, cucumber does load the CSS when I get good old Firefox to pop up and run for me. Therefore, I feel that my question now becomes: Is there a way to tell cucumber to render the CSS *without* a browser being loaded?

```
def hi_there(options = {})
  click_button('hi there')
  expect(page).to have_content("HI THERE")

  # some other code for more testing
end
```

Comment: Because I need to check the content of the page. This determines if certain things are being loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

`I'm using CSS to convert it to HI THERE.`

This means that you are using `text-transform:uppercase;` property which would internally call javascript to convert the given text on the page. 
So you would need to install(if you haven't already) a javascript_driver and use it for your scenario.

Refer to **[Using Capybara with Cucumber](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber)** here.